# Disable USB port containing Bluetooth Adapter on Laptop suspension

Tags: usb, suspend, bluetooth

There are multiple problems with **external Bluetooth Adapter** attached to **one of the USB ports of my Laptop** after its suspension:

- The external Bluetooth Adapter is **drawing aditional power** when Laptop is in Suspension Mode
- The Wireless Mouse that is connected to that external Bluetooth Adapter **can wake up computer at any time** from Laptop's Suspension Mode.

I would like to know if there is any way to configure Ubuntu, to **Turn Off** this external Bluetooth Adapter completely while the computer is in Suspension Mode. **And Turn On external Bluetooth Adapter when Laptop Computer Wake up** from the Suspension Mode.

```
naudotojas@naudotojas-N53SV:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:    19.04
Codename:   disco
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better, much simpler, to disable wake-up on mouse/keyboard?

Comment: Hmm, I doubt that it would work, since I just found out that **external bluetooth adapter** is randomly waking up the computer all by itself, without the mouse being present/connected.

Comment: So, disable all other wake-up features if you don't intend to use any. A Bluetooth dongle by itself should be waking up from suspension unless allowed by BIOS/UEFI settings.

Comment: There are no settings for Wake Up in the BIOS of that Laptop.

Comment: There must be, otherwise it wouldn't be waking up :)

Comment: It can also be some settings about the USB ports...

Comment: Trust me, I have seen a lot of BIOS/UEFI systems, there are none. 
I checked everything in the BIOS in the past 5 months. I have some experience with BIOS wake up settings, and there are none. The Laptop is 10 years old, and it turns on randomly every time *external bluetooth adapter* is left plugged into the USB port.